# right brackets for two common equations

Tags: align, brackets

I'm using right brackets for two common equations but I cannot align them:
The result is the following

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Best,

Rubén

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&y_e=Y_e e^{i(k_e x-\omega_e t)} \quad \textrm{for} \quad t<T\\
\left.\begin{aligned}
&y_f=Y_f e^{i(k_f x-\omega_f t)}\\
&y_b=Y_b e^{i(k_b x-\omega_b t)} \\
\end{aligned} \right\} \quad \textrm{for} \quad t>T
\end{split}
\label{eq:wv1}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to align in the given code?

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of work we can also align the equals signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\templen}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:wv1}
\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}
\settowidth{\templen}{$\displaystyle y_f$}
\newcommand{\y}[1]{\mathmakebox[\templen][l]{y_{#1}}}
\begin{aligned}
  & \y{e}=Y_e e^{i(k_e x-\omega_e t)} && \text{for } t<T \\
  & \left.\!\!
    \begin{aligned}
    & \y{f}=Y_f e^{i(k_f x-\omega_f t)} \\
    & \y{b}=Y_b e^{i(k_b x-\omega_b t)}
  \end{aligned} \right\} && \textrm{for } t>T
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

We need to remove some additional spaces that are inserted by TeX: one is `\nulldelimiterspace`, the other one stems from the inner `aligned` that we can nullify with `\!\!`.

I define a temporary command to make boxes that have the same width to accommodate the left-hand sides.

[image]